# Manipulating data before save with geddy

Tags: node.js, geddy

I have a few scenarios in my application where I need to manipulate the data before it is saved.

I have a CakePHP background so this I would normally do in a Model's beforeSave method.

Is there anything equivalent that I can do in my models in geddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Model events](http://geddyjs.org/documentation#modelsevents).

> Both the base model 'constructors,' and model instances are
>   EventEmitters. The emit events during the create/update/remove
>   lifecycle of model instances. In all cases, the plain-named event is
>   fired after the event in question, and the 'before'-prefixed event, of
>   course happens before.
>
> The 'constructor' for a model emits the following events:
>
> - beforeCreate
> - create
> - beforeValidate
> - validate
> - beforeUpdateProperties
> - updateProperties
> - beforeSave (new instances, single and bulk)
> - save (new instances, single and bulk)
> - beforeUpdate (existing single instances, bulk updates)
> - update (existing single instances, bulk updates)
> - beforeRemove remove

For example:

```
var MyModel = function () { ... };

MyModel = geddy.model.register('MyModel', MyModel);

MyModel.on('beforeSave', function(data){
   console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: Not sure if I am implementing this correctly in my model as it results in User.on('beforeSave', function(){
     ^
TypeError: Object function () {

  this.defineProperties({
      email: {type: 'string'},
      password: {type: 'string'}
  });




} has no method 'on'

Comment: @wiseguysonly Updated my answer. I'm not sure tho, how to get the item being saved - so inside the `beforeSave` event try logging either `this` or `arguments` to see where the `item` you want to manipulate is. Let me know of your progress :)

Comment: Thank you that worked. I edited your answer to add the data argument to the anonymous function. With this I can then do data.password etc